# POST Request for send JSON file in Qt5

Tags: c++, json, post, qt5

I have a little problem for send a JSON file to a server with a POST request with the help of Qt5. I give you a piece of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QCommandLineParser>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  QByteArray jsonDocument("{}");

  QUrl url("http://validate.jsontest.com/?json=");
  QNetworkRequest request(url);
  request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

  QNetworkAccessManager manager;
  QNetworkReply* reply = manager.post(request, jsonDocument);

  while(!reply->isFinished()) {
    a.processEvents();
  }

  std::cout << "Ok, Server response : " << response.toStdString() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

As this doesn't work on the server on which I have to send my file, I tested my code on a test server like valide.jsontest.com -> when you send a json to the server, it answer that your json is valid or not.

But with my actual code I receive this:

```
Ok, Server response : {
  "error": "A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]",
   "object_or_array": "object",
   "error_info": "This error came from the org.json reference parser.",
   "validate": false
}
```

So if I send the same minimal json object {} with Curl like that:

```
curl -X POST -d "json={}"  http://validate.jsontest.com
```

the answer is logically good :

```
{
   "object_or_array": "object",
   "empty": true,
   "parse_time_nanoseconds": 10874,
   "validate": true,
   "size": 0
}
```

I think I missed a piece of comprehension in my Qt code or in the mechanism of the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The servers request the sending of a json file through a particular parameter. For instance, I must used the parameter "json" to send a JSON file on the http://www.jsontest.com/ server. So my request must be like that:

```
QByteArray jsonDocument("json={\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"subtract\", \"params\": {\"minuend\": 42, \"subtrahend\": 23}, \"id\": 3}");
```

Furthermore, I had to replace:

```
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
```

by:

```
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Now, all is good :)